# How to control the speed of a auto scroll in uitextview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, nstimer

How do I control the speed of the scrolling text in a UITextView.  I am new to iOS and can't figure this one out. Below is the method I am calling to start the scroll.

```
[InputTextField scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([InputTextField.text length]-1, -1)];
```

I want to be able to change the speed of the scroll.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't change animation's speed of `scrollRangeToVisible` but you can use `contentOffset`

Be sure you using UITextView, this not work with UITextField

```
   uint offset1=-1; 
   uint offset2=0;

    UITextPosition *Pos2 = [_textView positionFromPosition: _textView.endOfDocument offset: offset2];
    UITextPosition *Pos1 = [_textView positionFromPosition: _textView.endOfDocument offset: offset1];
    UITextRange *range = [_textView textRangeFromPosition:Pos1 toPosition:Pos2];

CGRect result1 = [_textView firstRectForRange:(UITextRange *)range];
result1.origin.x=0;//reset x position to zero



[UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                      animations:^{

                     _textView.contentOffset = result1.origin;
}
completion:^(BOOL finished){                                                  
}];
```